# Question about two people falling into a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I’ve heard that IIRC if you have two people fall into a black hole such that they are just out of reach of each other, due to the way that geometry in the black hole works, they will forever stay out of reach for their entire fall, instead of getting close to each other.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If they are in free fall then yes due to tidal forces and the resulting spaghettification, but if they have rockets they can still accelerate towards each other, they can pick velocities between -c (effectively the fastest) and -∞ (effectively the slowest, in terms of proper time), see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565144/24093) where you can replace the photons with strong ultrarelativistic rockets.

Comment: Why are you still using this misleading animation representing the singularity as a point” when it is an infinitely long spacelike coordinate line? The animation also is misleading in that it shows the observers crossing the horizon at different times, which is unphysical. The flaw here is in assuming that the raindrop coordinates use the proper time of the falling observer, but this is not really true. On the proper clock of each of the two observers, the other crosses the horizon at the same time with him. While mathematically correct, physically this animation is meaningless.

Comment: @safesphere - Feel free to make a better one, no one is keeping you from writing your own answer.

Comment: I'm assuming a supermassive black hole here, tidal forces are low initially.

Comment: @blademan9999 - the only reason they can be out of reach of each other are tidal forces, otherwise we'd have Minkowski and everything could reach everything else.

Comment: Except no thrust is allowed.